# how to paste the shape below another shapes present in a slide in powerpoint c# interop

Tags: vsto

I am able to copy a shape from one slide and pasting it on another slide but while pasting, the shape getting pasted above on another exiting shape on destination slide (i.e. overlapping on other shapes ). **how can i paste it below of existing shape on slide.**

Answer (score 0):

after thinking i got answer of my own question. here is the code to achieve this

```
 // main code
float CalculatedTopValue=getPositionValueForTop(objPres.Slides[ppSR2.SlideIndex].Shapes);
objPres.Slides[1].Shapes.Paste().Top = CalculatedTopValue;



 private float getPositionValueForTop(Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shapes shapes)
                {
                    float CalculatedTopValue = 0;
                    foreach (Shape shape in shapes)
                    {
                        float top = shape.Top;
                        float height = shape.Height;
                        CalculatedTopValue =  top + height;
                     }

                    return CalculatedTopValue;
                }
```